# Senior Planning Manager - What's Next?

Tags: job-search, new-job, career-switch

My next opportunity is long overdue, but I still can't figure out the right move.

I have spent my entire career (9 years) working for a brand that has changed ownership 3 times in the past 3 years. I have 2 years of wholesale experience as an account executive and 7 years of merchandise planning experience. I am currently a Senior Planning Manager. That means my work is focused on budgets, forecasts, inventory management/optimization, promotional and pricing strategies, assortment planning, scenarios, analysis and anything else that has to do with driving revenue.

Each change in ownership brought a new group of relentless executives to prove myself to. I have learned a great deal, but it's time to stop getting taken advantage of and move on.

Am I "doomed" because all of my experience is in corporate retail? If I still have hope, what should I be looking for?

Comment: You should be looking for whatever will make you happy? If you like the role, maybe you should just try to shift to a more stable company? To have lasted through three changes of ownership, which is certainly a feather in your cap that would look appealing to employers.

Comment: From lots of TV programmes I have watched, the answer is "farmer".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to change industries as your question implies, you're not doomed. But you cannot start at the same level without personal connections of some kind who believe in you.

My advice is to discreetly ask around your network, you should have quite a varied and large professional network considering your role. See what exactly is available and decide if you want to move. Many people successfully move sideways into a totally different role through their network connections

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you 'survived' 3 ownership changes in your organisation shows that you are an asset that is worth keeping and that you are good in what you do.

So it is up to you to decide what you want to do next.

Be that a new challenge within the same sector or a complete career change.

I would say you are not being 'taken advantage' of, but paid to do a job. And you proved yourself capable many times over.

Answer (score 0):

Do something meaningful with, for and in your life. Don't understand your value as a subordinate of the economic world.

If you stay 5 years in an unmeaningful position, you will just be 5 years older and things will not be easier then. You might become full of boredom and resentment with lesser opportunities at your hands.